# Let G be a group with subgroups X,Y. Show that XY is a subgroup if either X or Y is a normal subgroup of G.

Tags: group-theory

I've found and understood the proof for XY=YX but am unsure about this next bit.
Show in particular that XY is a subgroup if either X or Y is a normal subgroup of G.

I really don't know how to approach this question.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of $XY$? What is the definition of being a subgroup?

Comment: @Emily: this result is proved in Hersteins Topics in Algebra text. Why dont you take a look

Comment: XY is the union of all left cosets of Y with representatives in X?

Comment: I am very much sure that this question is already asked here and it does have an answer.. please try checking $HK=KH$ instead of $XY=YX$

Comment: This is straight forward question? You can check in your text book and you can solve this theorem by using definitions.

Comment: Recall that $XY=YX$ means that, for any $a\in X$ and $b\in Y$ you can find $c\in Y$ and $d\in X$ such that $ab=cd$; this should make you start in the proof that $XY=YX$ implies $XY$ is a subgroup.

Comment: Thanks, Herstein was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Subgroup test : If $x_1y_1,x_2y_2 \in XY$ you want to show that
$$
z:= (x_1y_1)^{-1}x_2y_2 \in XY
$$
But
$$
z = y_1^{-1}x_1^{-1}x_2y_2
$$
Since $XY = YX$, and $x_1^{-1}x_2y_2 \in XY$, there exists $x_3\in X, y_3\in Y$ such that
$$
x_1^{-1}x_2y_2 = y_3x_3
$$
and so
$$
z = y_1y_3x_3 \in YX = XY
$$
Hence, $XY < G$